# How to put Laravel 4 custom pagination outside vendor file?

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

There are many guide in building custom pagination view in laravel 4 (I am using laravel 4.2, to be exact) I am following [this guide](http://benjaminkohl.com/post/custom-pagination-views-in-laravel-4) and it works fine.

The problem is that many guides tend to directly change the view in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/views`. I am using Git for source control, and following the default gitignore file, the whole vendor file is ignored by Git. I may change the gitignore file, but I think it is reasonable to keep it the vendor file untouched by Git as this should be handled by composer.

Then, I noticed that in the setting file `view.php`

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pagination View
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This view will be used to render the pagination link output, and can
    | be easily customized here to show any view you like. A clean view
    | compatible with Twitter's Bootstrap is given to you by default.
    |
    */

    'pagination' => 'pagination::slider',
```

Is there a way I can change the setting so that the custom pagination view can be put in other place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done this before, but just taking a quick look at the guide to which you referenced, it states:

> To begin developing your custom pagination view, create a subfolder called "pagination" (or whatever) in your application's views folder then create an empty view file called "mine.php".

Then later:

> The simplest way to begin developing your view file is to copy and modify one of the existing default pagination views.

I can understand how it may lead to confusion, but the author is not saying to create your new views inside of the vendor directory. The first statement referenced says to create your views inside your **application's views folder**. The later statement referring to copying and modifying an existing view means for you to copy the existing view from the vendor directory and place it into your new application directory.

So, the steps would be:

1. Create a new view folder in your application: `app/views/pagination`
2. Copy an existing view from the vendor folder and place it into your new pagination view folder, with a new name: `app/views/pagination/mine.php`
3. Update your `app/config/view.php` file to point to your new pagination view: `'pagination' => 'pagination.mine'`

Comment: Thank you. It is really confusing that it uses the same name "pagination". I see the different of :: and . after reading your answer.